# Labview--Input-Output Data delay

Tags: labview

I am a new labview user. I am trying to implement a controller in real time using labview. For that purpose, I started doing analouge input output exercise. As a part of learning process, I was trying to apply input on a system, get the data and feed it back through analouge channel. However, I noticed there is a signficant delay between input and output, It was about 1 ms. Then i thought of doing the simplest exercise. I generated an input signal read it through labview and feed it back again. So, basically its a task for ADC and DAC only. But still, it has the same amount of delay. I was under impression that if i do hardwared time data read and write, it would reduce the delay. But still, no change.

Could you help me out on this issue? Any kind of advice would be really helpful for me[image]

Comment: What is the setup? If it's a computer with a cDAQ crate attached via LAN, I'd expect some delay. Also, what's the rate of the clock? I guess the ADC returns a value in one cycle, and the DAC sets it on the next cycle, all plus some overhead. So at a rate of 1Hz, you'd get 1s delay.

Comment: Yeah, it's connected with LAN. my delay is 1 ms. I want a delay in micro seconds. 200-400 microseconds would work. 1 ms will never work for me

Comment: Welcome! What is your sample rate and to what have you set the buffer? Note that your setup first reads the data and then writes it. Thus, the writing *must have a delay*. So if you are sampling 1000 samples at 10kHz, you are effectively reading at 10 Hz (100ms) and consequently you are also writing at this rate -- and writing with an undefined but probably somewhere close to 100ms delay.

Comment: thanks for the explanation @max. My delay is 1 ms however, for my application, I need less than 1 ms

Comment: @ZayedAhmed what do you mean with "delay"? What is your sample rate and what is your writing rate (so how many samples are buffered in the DAQ-hardware?)

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing might be the result of the while loop method you're using.

The while loop picks up data from the AI once every time it goes around and then sends that to the AO. This ends up being done in batches (maybe with a batch size of 1, but still) and you could be seeing a delay caused by that conversion of batches.

If you need more control over timing, LabVIEW does provide that. Read up on the different clocks, sample clocks and trigger clocks for example. They allow you to preload output signals into a niDAQ buffer and then output the signals point by point at specific, coordinated moments.